# Adding color to repl prompt (node)

Tags: node.js, terminal, console, read-eval-print-loop, chalk

I find that adding color to the prompt in repl really helps to separate the outputs.  I achieved this by using NPM's chalk, but this adds a bunch of space between the prompt and the cursor.

```
var term = repl.start({
    prompt: chalk.blue('goose> '),
    eval: function(cmd, context, filename, cb){
        ...
    }
});
```

The prompt comes out like this ('|' is the cursor):

```
goose>              |
```

Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Found [Relevant problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075396/adding-colors-to-terminal-prompt-results-in-large-white-space).  Looks like the prompt length is set to the entire prompt string including the escape color characters.  Not sure if it's possible to get what I want using repl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out to be very simple:

```
var prompt = 'My fancy prompt >>> ';
rl.setPrompt(chalk.blue(prompt), prompt.length);
```

You need to specify the count of characters because `readline` doesn't understand that escape sequences are really displayed as zero width.

(This is based on Felix's answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Run this before `repl.start()`:

```
var readline = require('readline');
var hasAnsi = require('has-ansi');
var stripAnsi = require('strip-ansi');

var _setPrompt = readline.Interface.prototype.setPrompt;
readline.Interface.prototype.setPrompt = function() {
  if (arguments.length === 1 && hasAnsi(arguments[0])) {
    return _setPrompt.call(this, arguments[0], stripAnsi(arguments[0]).length);
  } else {
    return _setPrompt.apply(this, arguments);
  }
};
```

Dependencies: `npm install has-ansi strip-ansi`

Comment: You should probably mention that you have to npm install has-ansi and strip-ansi in order to get this to work.

Comment: You shouldn't monkey-patch readline library unless you *really* have to.